# Google Search Console: alternate URLs in XX that do not have return tags

Tags: google-search-console, internationalization, hreflang

on http://example.com/ server response with (response based on Accept-Language header):

```
HTTP/1.1 301 Found
Location: /en/
```

on http://example.com/en/ in page `<head></head>`:

```
<link rel="alternate" href="http://example.com/" hreflang="x-default" />
<link rel="alternate" href="http://example.com/it/" hreflang="it" />
<link rel="alternate" href="http://example.com/en/" hreflang="en" />
<link rel="alternate" href="http://example.com/es/" hreflang="es" />
<link rel="alternate" href="http://example.com/fr/" hreflang="fr" />
<link rel="alternate" href="http://example.com/ptb/" hreflang="pt" />
<link rel="alternate" href="http://example.com/chs/" hreflang="zh" />
<link rel="alternate" href="http://example.com/de/" hreflang="de" />
```

Google Search Console (old Web Master Tool) in International Targeting panal tell me:

```
URLs for your site and alternate URLs in 'x-default' that do not have return tags.
/  -->  http://example.com/en/

URLs for your site and alternate URLs in 'pt' that do not have return tags.
/  -->  http://example.com/ptb/

URLs for your site and alternate URLs in 'it' that do not have return tags.
/  -->  http://example.com/it/
```

etc. for each language....

what am I doing wrong?

Comment: You need to have those tags on the pages for each language too if you don't already. This points alt back to default lang. This question is answered here too if that helps: https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/67058/international-targeting-no-return-tags

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> URLs for your site and alternate URLs in 'x-default' that do not have
>   return tags. /  -->  http://example.com/en/

This means that http://example.com/en/ doesn't have x-default to http://example.com/

> URLs for your site and alternate URLs in 'pt' that do not have return
>   tags. /  -->  http://example.com/ptb/

http://example.com/ptb/ doesn't point to http://example.com/ with x-default

> URLs for your site and alternate URLs in 'it' that do not have return
>   tags. /  -->  http://example.com/it/

http://example.com/it/ doesn't point to http://example.com/ with x-default

Basically, you need to have absolutely the same hreflang alternate tags all over your website; on every language absolutely the same tags.