# International targeting - No return tags (but there are)

Tags: google-search-console, hreflang, international

I've read this post => [International Targeting "no return tags"](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/67058/international-targeting-no-return-tags)

because I have this error in my Google webmaster console

```
International Targeting | Language > 'de' - no return tags
```

Pages for Example
https://www.translationscloud.com/about
https://www.translationscloud.com/de/ueber-uns

Actually the english page points to the german page, and the german page links back to the english page. (Of course with "points" and "links" I refer to the hreflang tag)

So, I don't understand which is the problem :(
Maybe I mis-understood the meaning...

Can anyone help?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Strange, it looks right to me. Were the tags added recently? Note that you can click into the error and get sample URLs (if that isn't where you already got your example).

Comment: Links were added months ago :(

Comment: @Andrew any idea? If you check the source code of the page everything is fine, but i have this error :(

Answer (score 1):

Your pages have redirects which don't match the tagging, like  [features](https://www.translationscloud.com/features) adding a trailing slash & [about](https://www.translationscloud.com/en/languages) redirecting to the version without the /en/ in the URL.

So, you're telling Google that the English page is [/en/languages](https://www.translationscloud.com/en/languages) but then redirecting them to [/languages](https://www.translationscloud.com/languages) instead. That's probably what's throwing them off.

Comment: So you suggest me to remove x-default and replace en value with x-default one?

Comment: You could also set `x-default` and `en` to use the same `/about` URL, since English is your default language.

Comment: That was my doubt... can I use the same page for both?