# Redirect to canonical URL gives hreflang error in Google Webmaster Tools

Tags: google-search-console, canonical-url, hreflang, geotargeting

In my website the root page https://www.amolelingue.com/ has 301 redirect to canonical English URL https://www.amolelingue.com/en, which has two alternate versions (/it and /fi).

I'm getting following two errors in International Targeting of Search Console of Google Webmaster Tools:

- "no return tags", originating URL "/", alternate URL "https://www.amolelingue.com/en"
- "no return tags", originating URL "/", alternate URL "https://www.amolelingue.com/it"

Each of the three pages (/en /it /fi) lists itself as canonical version and also has hreflang-links to all three pages. For example English version has:

```
<link rel='canonical' href='https://www.amolelingue.com/en'>
<link rel='alternate' href='https://www.amolelingue.com/en' hreflang='en'>
<link rel='alternate' href='https://www.amolelingue.com/it' hreflang='it'>
<link rel='alternate' href='https://www.amolelingue.com/fi' hreflang='fi'>
```

Nowhere do I mention "/" as canonical URL, so why am I getting errors about it not having return tags? Have I done some error here or is Google Webmaster Tools reporting this incorrectly?

Comment: I think the problem is 301 redirection, the originating URL said only `/` means root page or homepage, and that homepage should link back to all alternative URL but it is not possible because of 301 redirection. Have you seen [this answer](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/67058/international-targeting-no-return-tags) to know what is the meaning of that error. I think you can keep the homepage without redirection and set the canonical link tag to /en page, means only that page will be index.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your configuration is incorrect. Rather than permanently redirect the root to https://www.amolelingue.com/en.

Either:

1. Do a *conditional* redirect, i.e. test the user's browser language and do a temporary redirect to the appropriate language page, `/en`, `/it` or `/fi`.
2. Don't redirect the root at all, and have a page on which users can select the version they want.

Then identify the root with `"x-default"` as follows:

```
<link rel="alternate" href="https://www.amolelingue.com/en" hreflang="en">
<link rel="alternate" href="https://www.amolelingue.com/it" hreflang="it">
<link rel="alternate" href="https://www.amolelingue.com/fi" hreflang="fi">
<link rel="alternate" href="https://www.amolelingue.com/" hreflang="x-default">
```

Google's documentation on `hreflang` is [here](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/189077?hl=en), and the relevant part is:

> […] the reserved value "x-default" is used for indicating
>   language selectors/redirectors which are not specific to one language
>   or region, e.g. your homepage showing a clickable map of the world.

Comment: Google specifically tells that 301 redirect should be used when same page can be reached via different URLs, and one example specifically shows using this for homepage - https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/139066?hl=en#4

Comment: They do, but that's not what's happening here.

Comment: That is exactly what I am doing here - the English version has several (two) URLs so it uses 301 redirect - other two languages on the other hand only have single URL.

Comment: You misunderstand. If it was just a case of `example.com` and `example.com/home/` showing the same content, a 301 would be a valid solution and that's what the page you've referenced is describing. You, however, have three home pages in three different languages. This is a different problem, and that's what I've addressed in my answer.

Comment: So are you saying that it's just **impossible** to do what I would like to do - have English version reachable via two URLs and other versions from one URL?

Comment: No. If you do what I've advised, anyone hitting the root will get the homepage in _their_ language. If English, they'll get `/en`, etc. I can't imagine why you'd want the root to _only_ redirect to English, but if you do that it'll cause problems for SEO. You might find this helpful: https://medium.com/syzygy-london/a-guide-to-seo-for-international-websites-f43f721417d5

Comment: ok, I had missed option 1), i.e. that "x-default" can be used on pages using conditional redirect. I knew 2) but just don't like language-selector-pages. I'm still thinking which to implement, but I'll accept this answer as one of those seems to be the way to go.

Comment: Worth considering that, with `hreflang` properly configured, most people shouldn't see a language selector. For searches conducted in the languages you serve, the appropriate pages should be returned in search results.